# SAP HANA - How to use Distinct function without sumi

Tags: sql, hana

picture **1** is my original data in Hana Studio with a standard sql select statement
[image: Original Data]

Instead of getting the distinct value for the repeating values using the DISTINCT function, I do get SUM of the last two columns. Although the column BAN-Nummer is excluded. Picture **2**
[image: Picture 2]

If I transfer exactly the same data into ms sql server, I do get what I'm expecting.Picture **3**
[image: Picture 3]

**My question is**: How do I get the results in Picture 3 in the HANA Environment?
Will realy appreciate any help. Thnx in advance!!!

Comment: `SUM(DISTINCT)` to me indicates a data modeling error of some sort.  I have never used it.  You should also include the SQL as *text* in the question.  I would recommend making the data readable too, by using text tables rather than images.

Comment: Used images because it only three records. But thnx for the tip 

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you select from a Calculation View. Is it true? If so, it does summation inside it and works as designed, because the main purpose of Calculation View is analytical reporting. Aggregation should be modelled with additive key figures or hide all this complexity inside, so looks like you try to break the modelled behaviour or it is a design flaw.

Anyway, `DISTINCT` is not what expected to be executed against Calculation View even if you do

```
SELECT DISTINCT <your cols>
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM <your calc view>
)
```

It pushes the projected columns to the CV, so effective query is not different from

```
SELECT DISTINCT <your cols>
FROM <your calc view>
```

The only guaranteed way I know is to do

```
CREATE TABLE ... AS (
  SELECT * FROM <your calc view>
)
```

and then do select with summation over distinct column from this table.

Another *possible* way may be to wrap all this into SQLScript block, but this will work only if setting [*Propagate instantiation to SQL views*](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e8e6c8142e60469bb401de5fdb6f7c00/2.0.03/en-US/8a5d5228e41d4083b06e94d60756429b.html) is not selected (which also controls pushing of the selected columns into Calculation View).

```
DO
BEGIN

lt_data =
  SELECT *
  FROM <your calc view>;

SELECT DISTINCT <your cols>
FROM :lt_data;

END;
```